# Защита от слабого DDOS (SYN flood)

Tags: iptables, firewall, ddos, защита

Какой фаервол можно поставить на пару с iptables?И какое действенное правило можно создать что бы скажем банил IP если с него идет более 100 подключений или флуд.

Comment: Слабость это уязвимость![как вариант][1] [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/infosecurity/69854/

Comment: В очередной раз, вы различаете DDOS и (XSS, SQL inj)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы описали обычный DOS. Для него в iptables найдется правило:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN SYN -m limit --limit 100/sec -j ACCEPTiptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK,FIN SYN -j DROP
```